# How to remove PHP extension for pages served from a subdomain

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I just moved a development site from a virtual machine on my PC to a shared webhost in a subdomain and I'm getting a Forbidden error which I think is due to my .htaccess file.  Currently I've got it set up like so:

```
    Options +FollowSymLinks

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # Remove www prefix
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mysite.com/$1 [L,R=301]

    # Redirect to remove .php 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

    <Files ~ "\.inc$">
        Order allow,deny
        Deny from all
    </Files>
```

I tried commenting out the RewriteBase line and the "remove WWW prefix" bit which doesn't seem to help.  Currently my site resides at mysite.mysharedhost.com and I still need to be able to remove the PHP extensions from my files.  Am I missing something important or do you think my error is unrelated to my .htaccess file?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the rewrite module up and running?

Comment: You've got a different problem. If `mod_rewrite` is disabled, you get a `500 Internal Server Error` when using Rewrite directives. If you had any typo, you'd get a `500` as well. If it rewrites to non-existing files, you get a `404 Not Found`. So, if you get `403 Forbidden`, something else is wrong, nothing in the rewrite rules.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes could be the `AllowOverride` set to `none`?

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes Thanks, I should have known because I had earlier browsed to a page that rewrote the URL properly.  Now I've got to track down permissions problems I guess.  Thanks!